# Using Swagger with Django Rest Framework, can I see POST parameters in different fields instead of one body

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I'm actually create APIs on a Django Website using Django Rest Framework.
I'm trying to document them using Swagger.

I'm using Django 2.1, django-rest-swagger 2.2 and djangorestframework 3.11

Everything is nearly working as expected except something :

Let me explain you :

I have this model (models.py)

```
class Technology(models.Model):
    """
    This model defines the different technologies
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=CHAR_SHORT)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=CHAR_SHORT, validators=[validate_tech_path], help_text='this is only used to construct the url')
    image = models.ImageField()
    mailer = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    external = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    internal = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "technologies"
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then I have the corresponding serializer class (serializer.py):

```
class TechnologySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    This model defines the different technologies
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Technology
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'path', 'image', 'mailer', 'external', 'internal')
```

Finally I have my view with generated APIs (views.py):

```
class TechnologyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Technology.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TechnologySerializer
    http_method_names = ['get','post','delete','put']
```

Here's the result :

[Api description 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqYL6.png)
[Api description 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv8J4.png)

As you see on the picture above, the parameters are une the json body.

Is it possible to have something like this for all the parameters :

[API parameter wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ4Sa.png)
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ListCreateAPIView` instead of `modelviewset` you will be able to see your post https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview.

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView
class TechnologyViewSet(ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = Technology.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TechnologySerializer
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Hi Rohit, 
First of all, thank you for you answer. 
I've tried what you mentionned but got this error :
AttributeError: 'TechnologyViewSet' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'